# Nである程度 ― the degree to which one is N

Tags: grammar, translation, set-phrases

Looking up ある程度 on Weblio [yields a lot of phrases](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%A6) like

`Xである程度` --> to the extent that something is X

is this to be understood as **`Xである　程度`** 　or **`X　で　ある程度`**　？

I don't know if this is a set phrase or not, but what is the function of the で in this? Is it で、as in です's て-form, or is it connected to である？

If I wanted to say a phrase like

> **The degree to which something is expensive is dependent on the market price**

would I say

> **高価である程度は相場に基づいている？**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ある程度 is a common set phrase that means "to a certain extent/amount/degree", but it's not used in this sense in those ～である程度 examples on Weblio. They are `[Xである→]程度`.

In general `(na-adjective) + である程度` can be translated as `the degree of ～ness`, but I think `(na-adjective) + である程度` is not common. I feel it's a bit roundabout. For example, we usually say 危険さの程度, 危険の程度 or even 危険度, instead of 危険である程度. I don't know why Weblio has this many examples of ～である程度 even though they are far from idiomatic.

Likewise 高価である程度は相場に基づいている sounds weird to me, and I can't help seeing the set phrase ある程度 in this sentence (i.e, "It's expensive, and is more or less based on the market price"). Why not simply say 値段の高さは相場に基づいている or even 価格は相場に基づいている?

Comment: I could definitely translate it as that, but I was just looking to do something direct for edification's sake. The way you phrased it with `Nの程度` is intuitively how I would try to say it

Answer (score 1):

First "ある程度" means "on some leve or to some extent."

> "ある程度のお金を使う" = "spend a certain amount of money"

"ある程度" of "である程度" has different meaning from "(just)ある程度."

The followings are examples from Weblio,

> 頑固である程度 "the degree of obstinacy"
>   質素である程度 "the degree of simplicity"

### "〇〇である程度" = "〇〇である。その程度(level or degree)"

> "私の父は頑固である（＝私の父は頑固だ）。"、"どの程度頑固ですか？"、”頑固である程度を説明するのは難しいが、強いて言えば「牛のように頑固だ」”
>   "My father is stubbom." "How stuboom is he?" "It's hard for me to explain how stuboom he is, but to stretch a point, he is as stubbom as an ox."

Eeven through the phrase "である程度" is familiar for me, but when I try to make examples using "である程度," I found it's difficult.

Then, the following example is natural.

> "私の父は頑固である（＝私の父は頑固だ）。"、"どの程度頑固ですか？"、”どのくらい（程度）頑固か（を）説明するのは難しい。”

Anyway, you can understand "である程度" as one phrase.